# how to read array from php page?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, arrays

in my application i use the following code to retrieve a data from my server :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
NSLog(@"Want to redeem: %@", textField.text);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/iPhone/page.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];

// Hide keyword
[textField resignFirstResponder];

// Clear text field
textView.text = @"";

// Start hud

return TRUE;
}
```

now what should i do to get the content of my `$array` in the `requestFinished` function

Answer (score 0):

I must as the first thing, point you to the ASIHTTPRequest documentation at: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use. But what I think you want to do is pretty simple, like this:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}
```

I hope you find this useful, otherwise I would recommend you to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to format the php output into a format that can be parsed into an array...JSON or XML, and then use something like SBJSON or NSXMLParser (I suggest the former). Maybe the result is product information (as example) so your php would output:

`[{"id":123,"price":5.99,"itemName":"toy car"},{"id":456","price":0.99,"itemName":"hot coffee"}]`

then, you would

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSArray *responseArray = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
//do something with the array
}
```